# Why does my script work in RStudio but not when scheduled?

Tags: r, dplyr, scheduled-tasks, readr

I wrote some scripts, which I want to run periodically in the background. They work if I start them manually in RStudio. With scheduled scripts, I get an error, if I have a one, which loads some packages. With `lubridate`, it works fine. With `readr` or `dply`r I get an error:

> Fehler: package or namespace load failed for 'readr' in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  es gibt kein Paket namens 'fansi' Ausf?hrung angehalten

The same script works from scheduler and in RStudio, if I don't load `library(readr)`, without any more modifications. Fansi is installed.

I also saw an error for tzdb. I think, some packages uses some other basic packages (fansi, tzdb) in an incorrect manner.

Comment: Can you check if your R version in RStudio is the same as the one used by the scheduler?

Comment: When R version is the same check if the needed libraries are installed in the System Library. Possibly the scheduler cannot access packages in the personal library (User Library).
It might be helpful to know which tool you are using for scheduling your task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that R uses other library-pathes than RStudio. I saw it, with print(.libPaths()) in scheduler environment and in dektop environment. I didn´t find the place to change the path in R itself. But I choosed one of the library-paths from R in RStudio. Now everything works. Maybe, someone has a better solution.